# Trouble with errors in local Sugar instance

Tags: vagrant, localhost, sugarcrm

I'm having a problem with setting up a local Sugar instance on localhost in a vagrant VM. I created a local host instance from a backup file, which worked well the first time I tried it. But, after restarting vagrant about two weeks later, I get an empty grey screen and an error in the PHP log:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ramsey\\Uuid\\Uuid' not found in /vagrant/src/Cache/Middleware/MultiTenant/KeyStorage/Configuration.php:44
```

I deleted this instance and created another one from a different backup file. Again, it worked well initially. But after restarting vagrant today, I got the same error. This time, I looked into this error in more detail and managed to fix it by changing the use statement in `Cache/Middleware/MultiTenant/KeyStorage/Configuration.php` to "`use Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid`" (https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/217). But now I'm getting a new error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'LoggerManager' not found in /vagrant/include/entryPoint.php:121\nStack trace:\n#0 /vagrant/index.php(17): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /vagrant/include/entryPoint.php on line 121
```

This leads to 3 issues that confuse me at this point:

1) Why is this error thrown when a `LoggerManager` class does exist in `include/SugarLogger/LoggerManager.php`?

2) It seems that there is a more fundamental problem with this instance that prevents it from finding existing classes. I was thinking it might be a permissions issue and ran the [commands](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/#Setting_Permissions_Via_Command_Line) to set the required permissions (using vagrant:vagrant instead of apache:apache), but it had no effect on the error. What else can I try to troubleshoot this?

3) Why did this instance work well initially and started throwing errors after restarting vagrant?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you checked the cache file of Sugar's auto-loader (`cache/class_map.php`) yet? Are those classes and files listed in it? And does deleting that file change anything?

Comment: The classes and files referred to in the errors do exist in class_map.php. Deleting class_map.php has no effect on the errors. Thanks @Jay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out what the problem was, but it went away after I set up a new local instance using a backup of a newer Sugar version.